# Specify LinkDistance and LinkStrength for Curved Links in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, social-networking

I cannot get the linkDistance and linkStrength based on link value functions to work for curved links, how and where am I supposed to specify these parameters?

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBramson/uqe35657/1/) based on the Curved Links example in which the code

```
.linkDistance(function(d) { return d.value; })
```

is written in two different places (and currently commented out because it doesn't work in either place).  My best guess is that it belongs in the lower location, after force.links(links) is specified.  I thought maybe that wasn't working because `d` is referring to the bilinks instead of the links, so I changed it to

```
.linkDistance(function(d) { return d[3]; })
```

in which `d[3]` is the link.value stored in the bilinks and that also doesn't work.  Both versions return NaN errors.

I expected implementing this refinement to be easy and straightforward, so maybe it's just a simple and obvious thing I'm missing.  But nothing I've tried and nothing I've found online has helped me make any progress for a few hours so hopefully somebody out there knows what's going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both *linkDistance* and *linkStrength* function you will get the source and target node so depending on that, you can return the linkDistance value in this case i am returning *weight* of the target node:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target.weight; })
    .linkStrength(function(d) { console.log(d);return 2; })
```

In your case you doing

```
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.value; }) 
//this is going to return undefined, as there is nothing like that
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/uqe35657/2/)

**EDIT**

Since you need the link value in the link object add that value when you create the links like shown below:

```
var nodes = graph.nodes.slice(),
        links = [],
        bilinks = [];

    graph.links.forEach(function (link) {
        var s = nodes[link.source],
            t = nodes[link.target],
            i = {}, // intermediate node
            linkValue = link.value // for transfering value from the links to the bilinks
            ;
        nodes.push(i);
        links.push({
            source: s,
            target: i,
            linkValue: linkValue //add the link value
        }, {
            source: i,
            target: t,
            linkValue: linkValue//add the link value
        });
        bilinks.push([s, i, t, linkValue]);
    });
```

so now in the *linkdistance/linkStrength* function you can get the value

```
 var force = d3.layout.force()
        .linkDistance(function (d) {
        return d.linkValue;
    })
        .linkStrength(function (d) {
        console.log(d.linkValue);
        return d.linkValue;
    })
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/uqe35657/5/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Cyril, but I am trying to set the link distances and strengths based on properties of the links (which even [the horribly written documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) says is the normal thing to do), not properties of the nodes. So in your case `d` clearly refers to the link, and you get the weight of the target of the link. It seems that `link.value` should just get the `value` variable of the link (instead of the `target.weight` variable), but it doesn't work. Maybe it's this: ...being passed the link and its index, with the this context as the force layout

Comment: edited my answer and updated the fiddle to get linkValue :)

Comment: Yes, I see now.  Adding the linkValue variable when defining `graph.links...` isn't enough.  One also has to push the variable and its value to both of the drawn "links" as well because those are the ones that actually are drawn and effect the layout.  There are THREE kinds of links at play (1) graph links from data, (2) bilinks, and (3) drawn links.  I think I will rename the third kind "edges" to keep things clearer in my own code.  Thanks a ton for helping me out with that!